# How to get text in line with image in an HTML cell

Tags: html, css-grid

I am trying to get the image in the same horizontal line as the text in this html cell. The text *left-image* works correctly, but when I use the image, I get the text above the image. There is plenty of room in the window to display them in-line.(The problem persists even if the browser cannot read the image.)

```css
#center-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

div.cell {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid Blue;
  align-items: center;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">
  <div id="center-grid">
    <div class="cell">
      position banner
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRhJp.jpg" width="100">
      left-image
    </div>
    <div class="cell center">
      top-objects
      <br>center-objects
      <br>bottom-objects
    </div>
    <div class="cell right">
      right-image banner position
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you can please add an image to the snippet (a fully-qualified URL to an actual image, perhaps from a dummy image service) that demonstrates the problem, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The image is irrelevant. I did mention in the question that the problem persists even if the image cannot be read and you see the default image icon

Comment: @Psionman if you run your snippet you will see that this is not a minimal and reproducible example of your issue. There are no images at all nor a placeholder of a broken image. The snippet you provided is a fully valid example of a table that has nothing to be fixed

Comment: You could also leave the image source blank or pointing to the same non-existent source it was previously; the point was to have the image there. In any case, the default behavior for boxes in a grid is to be laid out as individual rows. Since the cell you have the text and image in is set as `display: grid`, with no indication of what rows/columns to use, it lays it out in three rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to achieve your desired effect:

You can give the left-hand cell

```
display: flex;
```

rather than

```
display: grid;
```

---

**Working Example:**

```css
#center-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

div.cell {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid Blue;
  align-items: center;
}

.cell.left {
  display: flex;
}

.cell.left span {
  padding: 12px;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">
  <div id="center-grid">
    <div class="cell left">
      <span>position banner</span>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRhJp.jpg" width="100">
      <span>left-image</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cell center">
      top-objects
      <br>center-objects
      <br>bottom-objects
    </div>
    <div class="cell right">
      right-image banner position
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This also helped me to solve the analogous problem in the right-hand cell, namely:
            .cell.right {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: flex-end;
            }